# Performance issue: HTML file size too big and slow rendering because of d3 visualization

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, r-markdown

I'm working on a report that combines D3.js and ggplot2 to visualize time series data for countries all over the world. I'm using D3 for the first time. In the report, ggplot2 is used on country level analysis and D3 chart is for indicator level. To be more specific, there's only one D3 charts for each indicator; while under each indicator, there could be 200 ggplot viz under one indicator for each country.

I ran the report for 5 indicators, I got a html file size of 50 MB, which literally cost up to 30 seconds to open in google chrome. Then I remove all D3 (there're 5 D3 scatter chart in the sample report), the html file size reduced to around 41 MB. I know after removing D3, the html is still big. But I wonder how come 5 D3 viz could take up to 10 MB? (I size each SVG canvas to width&height = 400) Could it be caused by DOM harboring all the data(just guessing, new to this area)? Is there any solution to reduce the D3 chart size to make html lighter?

And then I guess my second question is why the ggplot-only html is still that big? I am using R markdown to produce the report. And depending on indicators, the total rows of data(all country, one indicator) could be around 20,000.

I'm looking for better way to either reduce the html size or on-rolling rendering. Right now if I run the report for 20 indicators, it will get stuck(never finish rendering in Chrome)

Thank you so much! Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: If you put the raw data in a file, how big will that file be?

Comment: @kkesley 205 kb/indicator if saved as .RDS

Comment: I don't have any experience in R markdown, but to pinpoint the exact problem, can you try using sample data? e.g. 10 items with only 1 ggplot viz? that way we can tell whether it's the problem of ggplot viz or your 1000 visualizations

Comment: @kkesley Hi thanks for spending time on investigating. I re-run the report with sample data. Without ggplot nor D3, the html is 1261 kb. Without ggplot but with D3 the html is 3676 kb. With both ggplot and D3, html is 50942 kb. So it seems that it is ggplot that increases the final file size. Does anyone has suggestion on how to improve the rendering performance while keeping those charts?(Will try to resize ggplot)

Comment: can we see your code regarding the ggplot? it may be because the resolution of the chart

Comment: My code is very simple, I used anomaly package function to auto-generate ggplot and I add a top layer of geom_text() that's it. Basically just something like this: data %>% plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3, alpha_dots = 0.5) +  geom_text( data = filter(temp, anomaly == 'Yes'), aes(label= lubridate::year(year)),  hjust = -0.5, size = 3.5)    But I think the problem lies in Rmarkdown default setting that cause html to be heavy: https://www.zevross.com/blog/2017/06/19/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-images-and-figures-in-r-markdown-documents/ I'll explain below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this post that solves my problem: https://www.zevross.com/blog/2017/06/19/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-images-and-figures-in-r-markdown-documents/

My main take away is "R Markdown reports that are heavy on graphs and maps can yield large HTML files that are not optimized for web viewing." Because of the default setting on fig resolution is high. To solve my problem, I include fig.retina = 1 (the default setting is 2, which multiplies resolution by 2 to fit retina screen) as well as dpi = 72, that significantly reduce the output html size by half.

So my full setting in r visualization chunk:

````
```{r eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis', 
      out.width = '500px', dpi= 72, fig.retina=1}
```
````

Hope it'll help!